# Not being able to remove trailing spaces from character strings

Tags: r, excel

I have this very weird column of a data frame (which structure is "chr"):

```
metadata$dummy
  [1] "SKF1_sample_037 "  "SKF3_sample_040 "
```

The trailing spaces are already in the excel file. The file was saved as tab delimited text and is read in with

```
metadata <- read.table("some_name.txt", sep="\t", header = T,
                       fileEncoding='latin1', check.names = F, row.names = 1)
```

Note, that without the `fileEncoding='latin1'` argument, R cannot read in the file

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
      invalid multibyte string 3
```

The TRIM(X) function in excel does not work as well. The only way to remove the spaces is by manually using backspace in every cell, but this is impossible to do.

If i now want to remove the trailing spaces in R, nothing will work:

```
library(stringr)
metadata$dummy <- str_replace_all(metadata$dummy, fixed(" "), "")
metadata$dummy <- gsub(" ", "", metadata$dummy, fixed = TRUE)
metadata$dummy <- trimws(metadata$dummy, "r")
```

All of these commands do result in the same string with the trailing space

```
metadata$dummy
  [1] "SKF1_sample_037 "  "SKF3_sample_040 "
```

What kind of mistake on my behalf would cause this behaviour?

/edit:

I also was not able to remove any space from the text file with a simple "replace any space with nothing"-command in notepad++

Comment: It's probably not a space but a different unicode character that appears to be printed as one. Can you post the output of `charToRaw(sub("SKF1_sample_\\d{3}", "", metadata$dummy[1]))`? If it's an actual space it should be `20`.

Comment: I had to do it on the second value, as i did change the first one already manually in excel. But here: charToRaw(sub("SKF1_sample_\\d{3}", "", metadata$dummy[2]))
 [1] 53 4b 46 33 5f 73 61 6d 70 6c 65 5f 30 34 30 c2 a0

Comment: You could try using the `\s` regex special character which matches several types of whitespace, `gsub("\\s", "", metadata$dummy)`

Comment: @GregorThomas generally a good idea but does not work in this case.

Comment: @SamR You had definitely the correct answer in guessing that the "white spaces" are something different. I checked it, and apparently the file is full of these invalid strings.

Comment: Apparently, i did not see your answer, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You character is not a space, which is why `trimws()` does not work. You have a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). You should be able to generate one in a text editor with:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

(You need to use the num pad and not the number keys above the letters.)

To replace this character in particular you can do:

```
gsub(rawToChar(as.raw(c(0xc2, 0xa0))), "", metadata$dummy)
```

Alternatively you could list all the characters you want to keep. In this case I have put letters, numbers and underscore:

```r
gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9_]", "", metadata$dummy)
```

Comment: I used the gsub command, and it worked nicely. thank you very much!